# 755 folder in document root not readable by apache

Tags: linux, apache

**Story:** I deleted a directory `LogViewer` from the document root that was browseable and working perfectly. Later I decided to add it back but now apache wont show it.

```
drwxr-xr-x. 12 user group 4096 Jun 19 15:16 272
drwxr-xr-x. 12 user group 4096 Jun 19 15:17 273
drwxr-xr-x.  3 user group 4096 Jun 20 08:06 LogViewer
```

The 272 and 273 directories are browsable and work.

[image]

Output of `ls -lZ`:

```
drwxr-xr-x. user group system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 272
drwxr-xr-x. user group system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 273
drwxr-xr-x. user group unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 LogViewer
```

**What I've Tried:** 
I have restarted apache multiple times. I've stopped it, and started it. I've refreshed the browser, I've cleared cookies and all temp files.

**My Question:** Wtf?

Comment: Does your server have SELinux enabled? If so, include the output of `ls -lZ`

Comment: Thanks @DarkFalcon. The command `sudo /sbin/restorecon -R -v /path/to/LogViewer` worked! Please add as answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per: [SELinux doc](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/rhlcommon-chapter-0017.html#sec-sel-file-relabel)

> To make a folder viewable from a special user public HTML folder, it
>   needs to have a type that httpd has permissions to read, presuming the
>   Apache HTTP Server is configured for UserDir and the Boolean value
>   httpd_enable_homedirs is enabled.

Try this command:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_user_content_t LogViewer
```

Comment: I ran a variation `sudo /sbin/restorecon -R -v /path/to/LogViewer`  but it works.

Comment: @ogc-nick: not the case here, apparently, but there will also be cases when you give too many rights to files and apache will refuse to read or use the files for security reasons (ie, not giving any possible intruder more rights than he should have)